Exclude a particular java file from Javadoc aggregation
I am running the following command:
mvn install javadoc:javadoc javadoc:aggregate
on a multi sub-module maven project.
I need to skip a particular java file from aggregation phase but i can't modify the maven-javadoc-plugin configuration as pom is being auto generated.
Is there any way, I can add anything into my java file itself, so that it is skipped during the specified command execution?
Environment is java 17 and maven-javadoc-plugin: version 3.0.1
I did try to use
/**
* @javadoc exclude
*/

as well as
/**
* @javadoc
* @exclude
*/

Also: @hidden
But nothing works.

You need to configure this in the javadoc plugin, you can't configure exclusion in the javadoc comment. But you can only exclude packages, not individual classes, and/or hide information based on the access modifier. See also Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin - Excluding Packages (though note that that document seems to be partially corrupt at this time due to a build error).

Also, you may want to read Documentation Comment Specification for the Standard Doclet (JDK 21) which lists all the tags supported by the standard doclet, which does not specify a @javadoc, so it is unclear to me why you think that works. The only presence of an exclude is for the @serial tag, which only includes if a field is included in specific serialization documentation of a serializable class.

I just noticed that page shows the @hidden tag should work if you're using Java 9 or higher, so if @hidden does not work for you, you should really provide a [mre]. I've just tried @hidden with Java 17, and it should work.
